# Does not match any available view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an error when I tried to receive email via sender.

```
var htmlEmailText = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync(
    "Emails/ConfirmationEmailTemplate", emailModel);

await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(
    model.Email, "Confirm your email", htmlEmailText);
```

It **works perfect locally**, but after deploying I have an error in the logs:

> Parameter name: Emails/ConfirmationEmailTemplate does not match any available view (8e09fd17)
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: Emails/ConfirmationEmailTemplate does not match any available view

Any suggestions what it can be?

Comment: To me at first, it sounds like a difference in folder structure between your local system and the deployed version, so that it can not find the template.

Comment: Have you deployed the views to the production environment? Are the views compiled into your app?

Comment: What is your `RenderToStringAsync()` method? And have you tried adding teh extension - i.e. `"Emails/ConfirmationEmailTemplate.cshtml"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke The file extension to file template should be excluded - refer to [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7429). Most possible cause is difference in folder structure on the production version compared to local one.

Comment: This [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/issues/191#issuecomment-324435628) looks like it might be relevant here.

Comment: How can I compare Deployed Files and Folders with Their Local Versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your **views are deployed as precompiled files** (not as `schtml` view files). To keep them published as view files you need to disable [`MvcRazorCompileOnPublish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation) in your `csproj` file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>MyWebProject.Namespace</AssemblyName>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Your recommendation +

`<Target Name="CopyCustomContentOnPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmailFile Include="Emails/ConfirmationEmailTemplate.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(Emails)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)%(Emails/ConfirmationEmailTemplate)" />
</Target>`

And It WORKS! Great, thanks!!!